# How to make trendline dashed in Google line chart?

Tags: web, google-visualization

I am trying to use trendline in my website and wants to make it dashed but lineDashStyle is not working under trendline option . Is it possible to make trendline dashed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are no standard chart options for modifying the trendline dash style
however, the chart can be changed manually, on the chart's `'ready'` event

the trendline will be represented by an svg `<path>` element, once found,
set attribute `stroke-dasharray` to the dash style you want

```
path.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', '5, 5');
```

(MDN web doc --> [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray))

see following working snippet,
the trendline's color is used to find the `<path>` element,
set the color with chart option --> `trendlines.n.color`
where `n` is the trendline's series index...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Value'],
    [new Date(2017, 02,10),100],
    [new Date(2017, 02,21),150],
    [new Date(2017, 02,28),160],
    [new Date(2017, 03,07),150],
    [new Date(2017, 03,14),125],
    [new Date(2017, 03,23),130],
    [new Date(2017, 03,31),135],
    [new Date(2017, 04,07),140],
    [new Date(2017, 04,26),145],
    [new Date(2017, 05,03),130],
    [new Date(2017, 05,10),150],
    [new Date(2017, 05,17),165],
    [new Date(2017, 05,25),175],
    [new Date(2017, 06,05),180],
    [new Date(2017, 06,12),100]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 48,
      height: '100%',
      left: 48,
      right: 16,
      top: 48,
      width: '100%'
    },
    colors: ['#c3d5bc'],
    hAxis: {
      format: 'M/d/yy',
      slantedText: 'true'
    },
    height: '100%',
    legend: {
      alignment: 'start',
      position: 'top'
    },
    trendlines: {
      0: {
        color: '#344f35',
        type: 'linear'
      }
    },
    width: '100%'
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(container);

  // change trendline to dashed
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var pathElements = container.getElementsByTagName('path');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(pathElements, function(path) {
      if (path.getAttribute('stroke') === options.trendlines[0].color) {
        path.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', '5, 5');
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

note: manual changes made to the chart will not be displayed,
when using chart method --> `getImageURI` -- to produce an image of the chart
use [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) instead...

Answer (score 1):

Could be done with *css*, searching by color:

```
google-chart path[stroke='#f2994a'] {
  stroke-dasharray: 6, 6;
}
```